# Notepad++, shortcut to add brackets around highlighted text

Tags: replace, macros, notepad++

I recorded a macro to type curly braces {} using a given shortcut

Can I record a macro that takes **any** given highlighted text (word(s)), and adds the curly braces around it?

So I can highlight the words:

```
test here
```

and click the shortcut created with a macro, and turn the text to:

```
{test here}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work with one or many words:

```
1) Mark text
2) Goto Macro -> start recording
3) Cut highlighted text (CTRL+X)
4) Type: "{" then do CTRL-V then Type "}"
5) goto Macro -> Stop Macro
6) Save Macro as a shortcut
```

this should do the trick

Comment: should be CTRL+X for cut ...but otherwise nice solution!

Comment: That`s right, corrected :)

Answer (score -1):

Might be this should help:

TextFX > TextFX Edit > Indent and surround { text line }